# KnexJs - Sqlite3 On Delete cascade doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, knex.js, objection.js, node-sqlite3

i'm trying to make onDelete('CASCADE') work on knex js but it doesn't seem to work at all.
Here's my knexjs migrations :

```
const tableName = 'users'

exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable(tableName, table => {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('username');
      table.string('email');
      table.string('password');
      table.timestamps(true,true);
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName);
};
```

```
const tableName = 'todolists';

exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable(tableName, table => {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('title');
      table.boolean('completed').defaultTo(false);
      table.timestamps(true,true);

      table.integer('users_id').unsigned().notNullable();
      table.foreign('users_id').references('users.id').onDelete('CASCADE');
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName);
};
```

When i try to delete users table, their respective todolists aren't removed and still reference the deleted user's ids.

Here's the Sqlite3 CLI schema definition and it seems the onDelete('CASCADE') is ON.

```
sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `username` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `password` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

```
sqlite> .schema todolists
CREATE TABLE `todolists` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `title` varchar(255), `completed` boolean default '0', `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `users_id` integer not null, foreign key(`users_id`) references `users`(`id`) on delete CASCADE);
```

Am I missing something ?

thanks for the help.

EDIT : 
Turns out i needed to first  foreign key support on the Sqlite side (it's an SQlite related issue, not related to knex/objection js)
I ran this line code in my program just after initializing knex js :

```
await knex.raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
```

This enables foreign key support and takes into account the "on delete CASCADE" constraint in my Schema definition.

Comment: Did you turn on foreign key enforcement? https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

Comment: Hi, i was just about to answer my own question as after doing some research this time concentrating on the Sqlite side rathern thatn on knexjs i found out that this was indeed the problem, i'll edit my question and post the response. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: recently, same functionality  was brooked and fixed - https://github.com/knex/knex/pull/4225

Answer (score 3):

i'm trying to make onDelete('CASCADE') work on knex js but it doesn't seem to work at all.
Here's my knexjs migrations :

```
const tableName = 'users'

exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable(tableName, table => {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('username');
      table.string('email');
      table.string('password');
      table.timestamps(true,true);
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName);
};
```

```
const tableName = 'todolists';

exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable(tableName, table => {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('title');
      table.boolean('completed').defaultTo(false);
      table.timestamps(true,true);

      table.integer('users_id').unsigned().notNullable();
      table.foreign('users_id').references('users.id').onDelete('CASCADE');
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName);
};
```

When i try to delete users table, their respective todolists aren't removed and still reference the deleted user's ids.

Here's the Sqlite3 CLI schema definition and it seems the onDelete('CASCADE') is ON.

```
sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `username` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `password` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

```
sqlite> .schema todolists
CREATE TABLE `todolists` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `title` varchar(255), `completed` boolean default '0', `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `users_id` integer not null, foreign key(`users_id`) references `users`(`id`) on delete CASCADE);
```

Am I missing something ?

thanks for the help.

SOLUTION : 
Turns out i needed to first  foreign key support on the Sqlite side (it's an SQlite related issue, not related to knex/objection js)
I ran this line code in my program just after initializing knex js :

```
await knex.raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
```

This enables foreign key support and takes into account the "on delete CASCADE" constraint in my Schema definition.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. May I ask where exactly in your code did you place this line ```
```? I am trying this blindly (and unsuccessfully). Thanks,

Comment: Hi, i don't understand your question, which line are you referring to ? If it is "await knex.raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');" you just place it in the file where you are initiating knex (where you call Model.knex(...) you can put that line after that call

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I was referring to that ```PRAGMA``` line (for some reason I couldn't edit my comment earlier). I have also figured out where and how to call it in my app. Thanks again.